# Nest.js + TypeORM. TypeORM didn't see .env file

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, nestjs, typeorm, cross-env

I have some issue about typeorm migrations. I have typeorm config (see below).

`data-source.ts`:

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/db/migrations/*.js'],
  synchronize: true,
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

And when I'm trying to start migrations, typeorm throws an error (but if I replace process.env with normal string, it works).

I attached scripts from package.json

```
"build": "nest build",
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nest start",
"start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
"typeorm": "npm run build && npx typeorm -d dist/db/data-source.js",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate",
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
"migration:down": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
```

I need the config to see data from env during migrations.

Maybe this is caused by the fact that I use cross env. And I read it like this

`App.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
...
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
    }),
  ],
...
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Anyway,I hope for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when running typeorm migrations, nestjs doesn't come into play. It's only typeorm. This should be clear as you're using TypeORM CLI (the command `npx typeorm ...`), and TypeORM has no clue that it is being used with NestJS.

So that code where you have `ConfigModule.forRoot` isn't called. That's why your .env didn't has read

One way to solve that is by using `dotenv` (the lib that `@nestjs/config` uses under the hood to read .env files into `process.env` object) directly. Follow their docs: https://npmjs.com/dotenv

Answer (score 2):

To deal with commandline migrations, you can use an additional `typeorm.config.ts` file on the root directory.

```js
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { resolve } from 'path';

config({ path: resolve(__dirname, '.env') });

const DataSourceConfig = new DataSource({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  migrations: ['./database/migrations/*'],
  synchronize: false,
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4',
  },
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
});

export default DataSourceConfig;
```

And to use typeorm inside NestJS app, create a `typeorm.service.js` file.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  public createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'mysql',
      host: this.configService.get<string>('TYPEORM_HOST'),
      port: this.configService.get<number>('TYPEORM_PORT'),
      username: this.configService.get<string>('TYPEORM_USERNAME'),
      password: this.configService.get<string>('TYPEORM_PASSWORD'),
      database: this.configService.get<string>('TYPEORM_DATABASE'),
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    };
  }
}
```

And load this service in `app.module.ts` file

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({ useClass: TypeOrmConfigService }),
  ]
});
export class AppModule {}
```

And then inside `package.json` file, define the commands. Note that I'm using the `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs` package because my `typeorm.config.js` file is in Typescript.

```
"migration:run": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d typeorm.config.ts migration:run",
"migration:create": "cd database/migrations && typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:create",
"migration:revert": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d typeorm.config.ts migration:revert"
```